# While I am installing Android Studio 3.0, I need to delete aapt2.exe located in Android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio

After uninstalling Android Studio, I'm in the middle of installing Build Tools revision 26.0.2. of Android Studio 3.0.
[This is the captured image of Android Studio 3.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXdHv.jpg)

If I click "Install Build Tools 26.0.2 and sync project", then the Component Installer pops up with fail as shown in following captured image.
[Component Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwuHH.jpg)

So, I need to delete  manually the aapt2.exe file located in Android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.2

I've tried to delete the file, but I can't do it as shown in the following image.  I've double checked the file path by deleting myMemo.txt located in the same folder.

Please help me to delete the aapt2.exe file.

[windows 10, cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Uf60.jpg)

[You require permission from the computer's administrator to make changes to this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi2Rn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact same problem and I solved it seconds ago.

What you need to do is:

In windows search for "Change User Account Control Settings" and then drag down the slider to "Never Notify". Click Ok. Then restart your computer.

After restarting the computer, go to the folder "26.0.2" and right click it then select properties.

Properties >> Security. Select Advanced.

Over there you will see a "Change" blue underlined text. Click on that.

Then on the third text field type your username. Then click check names.

Click Ok
Ok
Ok

Delete the folder

If it doesn't work

Restart

Delete the folder