# Android Studio - 3.0: COMPONENT INSTALLER FAILED

Tags: android, components, android-studio-3.0

ANDROID STUDIO 3.0

I am new to Android Studio.
Now, when I start a new project it successfully runs. But on the top, right below the tabs it shows an error.

`Gradle` project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly
[image: image 1]
Then I figure out the solution to by installing the required component from the message view:

Clicked on "Install Build Tools 26.0.2 and sync project

[image: image 2]

After trying to install the component, it shows me an error:

An error occurred during installation: Failed to move away or delete existing file

[image: image 3]

PLEASE HELP.
THANKS!

Comment: I am having the exact sample problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076264/while-i-am-installing-android-studio-3-0-i-need-to-delete-aapt2-exe-located-in?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just delete the folder below?

> C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.2

It seems that your android studio doesn't have permission to delete.

**Edited:**
Even though this is not a your original question, but...

If you doesn't have permission to access the folder, try this:

1. Goto parent folder of the folder you want to delete.
2. Right click the folder and select properties
3. Click secutity tab - Click advanced - Click owner
4. Click edit - Select user (your name) - Click apply

And you can delete the folder.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but I have ran into another problem: Folder Access Denied

Comment: this is your issue. Just leverage your access on your OS

Answer (score 0):

Run Android Studio as Administrator. Although I have local admin rights, updates failed and have since day 1, even on older versions too. On older versions running as admin didn't fix the problem, I did manual updates. Today I discovered that with 3.0 running as admin works great.

If you have a desktop icon, go to properties>Shortcut>Advanced and check "Run as Administrator". Now every time you run from the shortcut, you will run as  administrator. At least it fixed my problems.